# How to use dynamic placeholder text for comment field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field that I would like to use as placeholder text in the textarea on the comments field, but i'm not sure how to insert it into the code correctly. Grateful for any help!

Functions.php code:

```
function sabretooth_textarea_placeholder( $fields ) {
    $fields['comment_field'] = str_replace(
        '<textarea',
        '<textarea placeholder="Comment field placeholder text here please"',
        $fields['comment_field']
    );
```

Custom field code:

```
get_field('comment_field_placeholder', pll_get_post(881));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out myself :)

```
function sabretooth_textarea_placeholder( $fields ) {
    $comment_placeholder = get_field('comment_field_placeholder', pll_get_post(881));
    $fields['comment_field'] = str_replace(
        '<textarea',
        '<textarea placeholder="' . $comment_placeholder . '"',
        $fields['comment_field']
    );
```